# HTML Link To Textbox

Tags: php, html

Can I able to retrieve the string value of a link and put it in the textbox on different PHP page? I'm using my first column as the link.

Like this:

```
        <tr>
            <td><a href="form.php?"><?php echo  $row['Control_Num']; ?></a></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Date_Req'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Date_Rev'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Rev_by'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Requester'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Dept'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['cont_num'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['serv_req'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['purpose'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['app_by'];?></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: <a href="link"> text string</a> which value do you want the link page? or the text display of a link? " href=link"  or "<a> text string "

Comment: you mean you want to get value from url and set into the text box ?

Comment: Yes, I want to get the URL string to a textbox on a different php page.

Answer (score 0):

> This is href link "http://www.example.com" which you want to redirect that

```
<script>
    var burl = "http://www.example.com";
</script>  

<p><a href="" class="burl" data-extra="/textstring"> textstring</a></p>
```

> retrieve the string value of a link

```
 <script>
(function() {
   Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("a.burl"), 
    function(link) {
  link.href = burl + link.getAttribute("data-extra");
  });
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer.